# Static constants' values are not displayed in Spring MVC form action element

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a static import of my `Utility` class:

```
<%@ page import="static com.groupgti.webclient.util.MappingUtils.*" %>
```

I have some constants in this class:

```
public static final String HTM = ".htm";

public static final String SECURE_REQUEST_MAPPING = "/secure/";

public static final String CANDIDATE_DETAILS_DATA_FORM_MAPPING = "assessments/candidate-details-data";
```

I have a Spring MVC form:

```
<form:form cssClass="springForm"
        action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}<%=SECURE_REQUEST_MAPPING + CANDIDATE_DETAILS_DATA_FORM_MAPPING + HTM%>"
        commandName="assessments/candidate-details-request">
</form:form>
```

Why when I am using like this:

```
<a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}<%=SECURE_REQUEST_MAPPING + CANDIDATE_DETAILS_DATA_FORM_MAPPING + HTM%>">
   some text
</a>
```

Value of `href` attribute is generated correctly, and in spring form `action` attribute the HTML code is like this: `/webclient<%=SECURE_REQUEST_MAPPING + CANDIDATE_DETAILS_DATA_FORM_MAPPING + HTM%>`. The values of those constants are not shown. Why is that and what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP allows you to use scriptlet expressions (`<%= ... %>`) in attributes of custom tags (such as `<form:form>`), but it must be the only content of the attribute. Therefore you cannot mix `<%= ... %>` expression with EL expressions or plain text in attributes of custom tags.

However, you can use any content in attributes of regular HTML tags, because these tags have no special meaning for JSP, that's why it works with `<a>`.

One possible solution is to put a result of scriptlet expression into request attribute and use it in EL expression:

```
<c:set var = "url" 
    value = "<%=SECURE_REQUEST_MAPPING + CANDIDATE_DETAILS_DATA_FORM_MAPPING + HTM%>" />
<form:form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}${url}" ...>
    ...
</form:form>
```

Alternatively, you may choose to use scriptlets without EL, for example, by defining a method that appends context path in your `MappingUtils`:

```
... <%= url(...) %> ...
```

Note that for historical reasons (EL expressions were designed to replace scriptlets) JSP doesn't provide elegant ways to mix EL and scriptlets, therefore this kind of problems is pretty much expected.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand why is that and your solution works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since at work we're not allowed to inline Java in JSP, I use custom tag to "import" static final class fields in JSP. It's slightly modified `UseConstantsTag` from abandoned Jakarta 'unstandard' custom tag library API using Spring Framework's utils and with generic support. (I can't even find original code at the moment; here's [original API documentation](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/sandbox/doc/unstandard-doc/javadoc/org/apache/taglibs/unstandard/UseConstantsTag.html).)

This tag basically exposes all static final fields (via reflection) as `Map` which can easily be used in JSP. **[Take a look at full code in this gist](https://gist.github.com/3793543)**, essence is:

```
/**
 * Tag that exposes all of the public constants in a class as a map stored in
 * a scoped attribute. The scope may be specified, but defaults to page scope.
 * <p/>
 * Based on abandoned project taglibs-unstandard, specifically
 * {@code org.apache.taglibs.unstandard.UseConstantsTag}. Uses Spring's TagUtils
 * and ClassUtils instead of utils bundled in taglibs-unstandard, plus it
 * supports generics.
 * 
 * @see http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/unstandard
 */
public class UseConstantsTag extends TagSupport {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  /**
   * The fully qualified name of the Java class for which constants are to be
   * exposed.
   */
  private String className;

  /**
   * The scope in which the exposed map will be stored.
   */
  private String scope = TagUtils.SCOPE_PAGE;

  /**
   * The name of the scoped attribute in which the constants will be stored.
   */
  private String var;

  /**
   * Construct an instance of this class.
   */
  public UseConstantsTag() {
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the name of the class for which constants are to be exposed.
   * 
   * @return The fully qualified class name.
   */
  public String getClassName() {
    return className;
  }

  /**
   * Set the name of the class for which constants are to be exposed.
   * 
   * @param className The fully qualified class name.
   */
  public void setClassName(final String className) {
    this.className = className;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the scope in which the exposed map will be stored.
   * 
   * @return The name of the scope.
   */
  public String getScope() {
    return scope;
  }

  /**
   * Set the scope in which the exposed map will be stored.
   * 
   * @param scope The name of the scope.
   */
  public void setScope(final String scope) {
    Assert.notNull(scope, "Scope cannot be null");
    this.scope = scope;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve the variable name in which the exposed map will be stored.
   * 
   * @return The name of the variable.
   */
  public String getVar() {
    return var;
  }

  /**
   * Set the variable name in which the exposed map will be stored.
   * 
   * @param var The name of the variable.
   */
  public void setVar(final String var) {
    this.var = var;
  }

  /**
   * Expose the constants for a class as a scoped attribute.
   * 
   * @return A constant that identifies what the container should do next.
   * 
   * @throws JspException if a fatal error occurs.
   */
  @Override
  public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    if (className != null && var != null) {
      Map<String, Object> constants;
      try {
        constants = ClassReflectionUtils.getClassConstants(className);
      } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new JspTagException("Class not found: " + className, e);
      } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new JspTagException("Illegal argument: " + className, e);
      } catch (final IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new JspTagException("Illegal access: " + className, e);
      }
      if (!constants.isEmpty()) {
        pageContext.setAttribute(var, constants, TagUtils.getScope(scope));
      }
    }

    return SKIP_BODY;
  }

  /**
   * Free up any resources being used by this tag handler.
   */
  @Override
  public void release() {
    super.release();
    className = null;
    scope = null;
    var = null;
  }

}
```

and

```
/**
 * Utility class for working with Class instances.
 */
final class ClassReflectionUtils {

  /**
   * Private constructor to prevent instantiation of this class.
   */
  private ClassReflectionUtils() {
  }

  /**
   * Creates and returns a map of the names of public static final constants to
   * their values, for the specified class.
   * 
   * @param className The fully qualified name of the class for which the
   *                  constants should be determined
   * 
   * @return {@code Map<String, Object>} from constant names to values
   * @throws ClassNotFoundException
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException
   */
  public static Map<String, Object> getClassConstants(final String className)
      throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException,
      IllegalAccessException {
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    final Class<?> clazz = ClassUtils.forName(className,
        ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader());

    for (final Field field : clazz.getFields()) {
      final int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
      if (Modifier.isPublic(modifiers) && Modifier.isStatic(modifiers)
          && Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
        // null as argument because it's ignored when field is static
        final Object value = field.get(null);
        if (value != null) {
          constants.put(field.getName(), value);
        }
      }
    }
    return constants;
  }

}
```

Tag definition:

```
<tag>
    <name>useConstants</name>
    <tag-class>com.github.xaerxess.UseConstantsTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>

    <display-name>useConstants</display-name>

    <description>
    Exposes all of the public constants in a class as a map stored in
    a scoped attribute. The scope may be specified, but defaults to page
    scope.
     </description>

    <variable>
        <name-from-attribute>var</name-from-attribute>
        <variable-class>java.lang.Object</variable-class>
        <declare>true</declare>
        <scope>AT_BEGIN</scope>
        <description>The name of the attribute into which the map will be stored.</description>
    </variable>

    <attribute>
        <name>var</name>
        <required>yes</required>
        <rtexprvalue>no</rtexprvalue>
        <description>Name of the scoped attribute into which the map will be stored.</description>
    </attribute>

    <attribute>
        <name>className</name>
        <required>yes</required>
        <rtexprvalue>no</rtexprvalue>
        <description>Fully qualified name of the class from which constants will be extracted.</description>
    </attribute>

    <attribute>
        <name>scope</name>
        <required>no</required>
        <rtexprvalue>no</rtexprvalue>
        <description>Scope into which to store the map. Default is page scope.</description>
    </attribute>

    <example>
To expose all of the constants in the Integer class:
<![CDATA[<un:useConstants var="const" className="java.lang.Integer" />]]> 
    </example>
</tag>
```

Use it like:

```
<custom:useConstants var="MappingUtils" 
    className="com.groupgti.webclient.util.MappingUtils" scope="application" />
```

and then:

```
<p>My const: ${MappingUtils.SECURE_REQUEST_MAPPING}</p>
```